# INTERNAL SERVER ERROR in django with json

Tags: django, json, django-views

I have a form which is submitted via AJAX and uploads files. However, although the files are properly uploaded, the javascript shows an `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` after uploading. I know the file is added to the database and uploaded to the server; everything seems to be working as intended except for this error message. No error messages seem to be in the Django logs.

I also didn't write the code that deals with javascript, so there may actually be a much better way of doing this or something obvious that I'm overlooking.

It seems that the error happens because of this line:

```
response = JSONResponse(data, {}, response_mimetype(self.request))
```

In my views.py:

```
def response_mimetype(request):
    if "application/json" in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']:
        return "application/json"
    else:
        return "text/plain"

class UploadedFileCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UploadedFile
    form_class = UploadedFileForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.project_id = self.kwargs['proj_key']
        self.object.save()
        f = self.request.FILES.get('file')

        data = [{
            'name': self.object.name(),
            'url': "/uploads/xmlfiles/" + self.object.name().replace(" ", "_"),
            'delete_url': reverse('fileupload:upload-delete',
                kwargs={'pk':self.object.id,
                'proj_key':self.kwargs['proj_key']}),
            'delete_type': "DELETE"}]


        # the problem line
        response = JSONResponse(data, {}, response_mimetype(self.request)) 
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return super(UploadedFileCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UploadedFileCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['files'] = UploadedFile.objects.all()
        context['proj'] = int(self.kwargs["proj_key"])
        return context

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """JSON response class."""
    def __init__(self,obj='',json_opts={},mimetype="application/json",*args,**kwargs):
        content = simplejson.dumps(obj,**json_opts)
        super(JSONResponse,self).__init__(content,mimetype,*args,**kwargs)
```

I thought the problem might be the `reverse` method, but everything is working fine there. Just in case, here's the line from urls.py:

```
(r'^projects/(?P<proj_key>\d+)/d/(?P<pk>\d+)$', UploadedFileDeleteView.as_view(), {}, 'upload-delete'),
```

And the relevant model:

```
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    """This represents a file that has been uploaded to the server."""
    STATE_UPLOADED = 0
    STATE_ANNOTATED = 1
    STATE_PROCESSING = 2
    STATE_PROCESSED = 4
    STATES = (
        (STATE_UPLOADED, "Uploaded"),
        (STATE_ANNOTATED, "Annotated"),
        (STATE_PROCESSING, "Processing"),
        (STATE_PROCESSED, "Processed"),
    )

    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATES,
        default=0, blank=True, null=True) 
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.XML_ROOT)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file.name

    def name(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.status:
            self.status = self.STATE_UPLOADED
        super(UploadedFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        os.remove(self.file.path)
        self.file.delete(False)
        super(UploadedFile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT: just noticed this 500 error in the console, but I'm not sure where I can find a stack trace (since I don't see an error template):

```
[29/Oct/2013 23:38:56] "POST /upload/projects/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 11939
```

Comment: if 500 you should see a stacktrace somewhere, could you post it please?

Comment: I'm not getting a 500 error, at least nowhere that I can see (log file, console).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the definition of the `JSONResponse` class *before* the `UploadedFileCreateView` class; the error happens there before you are calling the class when it hasn't been defined yet.

The object gets saved because you have already saved it before you call the `JSONReponse` class:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.project_id = self.kwargs['proj_key']
    self.object.save() # object gets saved successfully here
    f = self.request.FILES.get('file')

    # ...


    # Here, JSONResponse is not defined yet, so this is resulting in a 500
    # since you have debug=False, its resulting in the default 500 error template
    # from your server.
    response = JSONResponse(data, {}, response_mimetype(self.request))
```

Comment: No, that's not the issue - I still have the same problem. Why does everyone think it's a 500 error? I haven't seen any specific error message, nor am I sure how I can see one (`INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` is the output of javascript, not django).

It's also worth noting that the file is actually uploaded to the server.

Comment: Actually, you're right - there is a 500 error, but I have no idea how to see the stacktrace since I don't see a template for it. I added the console log line to my OP.